# How do I find the impact pressure of cavitation due to imploding super critical fluid bubble?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, models

I have solved the Rayleigh-Plesset equation for a time varying bubble of a super critical fluid. I am trying to find if the impact pressure caused by SCF bubbles is lesser as compared to that caused by water bubbles. Here is the equation I arrived at:
 $$xx^{\prime\prime} +(3/2)\left(x^\prime\right)^2 + A\left(x^\prime/x\right) = W$$

Here A and W are constants that depend on the viscosity, temperature and specific heat of the fluid continuum. I have used Weierstrass' elliptic function to find an analytical solution for this second order, nonlinear equation. I have used the Chapman-Enskog theory for finding the viscosity of the SCF and its distribution.
This is the result of the viscosity from the modified Chapman-Enskog theory:
[image]

This is the equation I arrived at:[image]

My question is how do I go about finding the impact pressure of such a system? And how do I model their distribution by a mathematical distribution?

Comment: Hi Naveen. Please do use MathJax; this is a MathJax-enabled site. Using it would increase the readability of the post. For a quick revision of $\LaTeX,$ please check this Meta Math.SE  [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Sure, thanks a lot!Could you please help me out here.